# Почему не отображает несколько одинаковых элементов на странице?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Хочу для создания формы использовать такую штуку https://lusaxweb.github.io/vuesax/components/input.html#icons
Точнее несколько одинаковых инпутов на странице, но отображается только первый.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
С чем это связано ? И как это исправить?

Код:

```js
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data:{
      value1:'',
      value2:'',
      value3:'',
      value4:'',
      value5:'',
      value6:'',
      value7:''
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuesax/dist/vuesax.umd.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuesax/dist/vuesax.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
<vs-input label-placeholder="Default" v-model="value1"/>
    <vs-input color="success" label-placeholder="Success" v-model="value2"/>
    <vs-input color="danger" label-placeholder="Danger" v-model="value3"/>
    <vs-input color="warning" label-placeholder="Warning" v-model="value4"/>
    <vs-input color="dark" label-placeholder="Dark" v-model="value5"/>
    <vs-input color="rgb(213, 14, 151)" label-placeholder="RGB: rgb(213, 14, 151)" v-model="value6"/>
    <vs-input color="#11e988" label-placeholder="HEX: #11e988" v-model="value7"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Код в студию, пожалуйста

Comment: @Misha Saidov код добавил

Comment: решение проблемы нашел случайно. Просто нужно каждый ```vs-input```   обернуть в отдельный ```div``` или ```p```